# Junction tables not getting updated with SQLBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I have three tables like below and one company can have multiple locations

> Company - Id, Name ...
>
> Locations - Id, City, State, Country ..
>
> CompanyLocation, Id, CompanyId, LocationId

With below code company and location tables are getting updated, but the associated / junction table is not getting updated

```
// Create the SqlBulkCopy object.                
using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
{
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TargetTable;
    // Write from the source to the destination.
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceTable);
}
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Each [SqlBulkCopy object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) is linked to one SQL table specified by the [SqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.destinationtablename), as showed in your code. Hence, a solution to update your three tables would be to instantiate three [SqlBulkCopy objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx), one for each table.